# What Code To Add To TableSorter To Retrieve Data From A List Of Specific Columns?

Tags: jquery, xml, tablesorter, modx

I have a range of 34 districts and 34 postcodes in individually named columns in MySql and xml. A user inputs information and will select only 1 district and 1 postcode (also other information is input). This will leave 33 empty columns for postcodes and districts.

What code do I need to add to make TableSorter display (in child rows) only the single district and postcode that has been input and ignore the empty column (district & postcode) values?

I have TableSorter displaying most of my required data on the front end using the following code:

```
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <!-- jQuery -->


<!-- Tablesorter: required -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/theme.blue.css">


<!-- Tablesorter: pager -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/jquery.tablesorter.pager.css">


    <script>
    $(function() {

    $(".tablesorter")
    .tablesorter({
    theme : 'blue',
    // this is the default setting
    cssChildRow: "tablesorter-childRow",

    // initialize zebra and filter widgets
    widgets: ["zebra", "filter", "pager"],

    widgetOptions: {
    // output default: '{page}/{totalPages}'
    // possible variables: {page}, {totalPages}, {filteredPages},                     {startRow}, {endRow}, {filteredRows} and {totalRows}
    pager_output: '{startRow} - {endRow} / {filteredRows} ({totalRows})', // '{page}/{totalPages}'
    pager_removeRows: false,
    // set number of rows to show; make sure to include this
    // value in the select options
    pager_size: 100,  
    // include child row content while filtering, if true
    filter_childRows  : true,
    // class name applied to filter row and each input
    filter_cssFilter  : 'tablesorter-filter',
    // search from beginning
    filter_startsWith : false,
    // Set this option to false to make the searches case sensitive
    filter_ignoreCase : true
  }

});
 // hide child rows
     $('.tablesorter-childRow td').hide();

  // Toggle child row content (td), not hiding the row since we are using rowspan
  // Using delegate because the pager plugin rebuilds the table after each page change
  // "delegate" works in jQuery 1.4.2+; use "live" back to v1.3; for older jQuery - SOL
  $('.tablesorter').delegate('.toggle', 'click' ,function(){

// use "nextUntil" to toggle multiple child rows
// toggle table cells instead of the row
$(this).closest('tr').nextUntil('tr.tablesorter-hasChildRow').find('td').toggle();

  return false;
  });

  // Toggle widgetFilterChildRows option
  $('button.toggle-option').click(function(){
var c = $('.tablesorter')[0].config.widgetOptions,
o = !c.filter_childRows;
c.filter_childRows = o;
$('.state').html(o.toString());
// update filter; include false parameter to force a new search
$('table').trigger('search', false);
return false;
  });
});
</script>


<div id="demo">

<div class="pager">
    <img src="../assets/images/first.png" class="first" alt="First" />
    <img src="../assets/images/previous.png" class="prev" alt="Prev" />
    <span class="pagedisplay"></span> <!-- this can be any element, including an input -->
    <img src="../assets/images/next.png" class="next" alt="Next" />
    <img src="../assets/images/last.png" class="last" alt="Last" />
    <select class="pagesize" title="Select page size">
        <option value="10">10</option>
        <option value="20">20</option>
        <option value="30">30</option>
        <option value="40">40</option>
        <option value="50">50</option>
        <option value="100">100</option>
    </select>
    <select class="gotoPage" title="Select page number"></select>
</div>

<table class="tablesorter">
<colgroup>
    <col width="85" />
    <col width="110" />
    <col width="110" />
    <col width="100" />
    <col width="100" />
</colgroup>
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Id No #</th>
        <th>Province</th>
        <th>Date</th>
        <th>Country</th>
        <th>Package Type</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <!-- First row expanded to reveal the layout -->
[[+innerrows.row]]
    </tbody>
</table>

   </div>
```

I want to add code to the following so to include as child rows the only selected district and postcode:

```
        <tr>
<td rowspan="4"> <!-- rowspan="4" makes the table look nicer -->
    <a href="#" class="toggle">[[+id]] - More info</a> <!-- link to toggle view of the child row -->
</td>
<td>[[+province]]</td>
<td>[[+date132]]</td>
<td>[[+country]]</td>
<td>[[+packagetype]]</td>
</tr>
<tr class="tablesorter-childRow"><td colspan="5"><div class="bold">Customer Name</div><div>[[+yourname]]<br></div></td></tr>
<tr class="tablesorter-childRow"><td colspan="5"><div class="bold">Phone Number</div><div>[[+phonenumber]]<br></div></td></tr>
<tr class="tablesorter-childRow"><td colspan="5"><div class="bold">Email Address</div><div>[[+email128]]<br></div></td></tr>
<tr class="tablesorter-childRow"><td colspan="5"><div class="bold">Company Name</div><div>[[+companyname]]<br></div></td></tr>
<tr class="tablesorter-childRow"><td colspan="5"><div class="bold">Package Weight</div><div>[[+weight]]<br></div></td></tr>
<tr class="tablesorter-childRow"><td colspan="5"><div class="bold">Package Width</div><div>[[+width]]<br></div></td></tr>
<tr class="tablesorter-childRow"><td colspan="5"><div class="bold">package Height</div><div>[[+height]]<br></div></td></tr>
<tr class="tablesorter-childRow"><td colspan="5"><div class="bold">Details</div><div>[[+details]]<br></div></td></tr>
```

Here is the xml including the 34 districts and postcodes:

```
    <model package="shipsaveeng" baseClass="xPDOObject" platform="mysql" defaultEngine="MyISAM" version="1.1">
<object class="ShipSave" table="shipsaveeng" extends="xPDOSimpleObject">
<field key="id" dbtype="int" precision="11" phptype="integer" null="false" default=""/>
<field key="province" dbtype="varchar" precision="255" phptype="string" null="false" default=""/>
<field key="district1" dbtype="varchar" precision="255" phptype="string" null="false" default=""/>
<field key="district2" dbtype="varchar" precision="255" phptype="string" null="false" default=""/>
<field key="district3" dbtype="varchar" precision="255" phptype="string" null="false" default=""/>
<field key="district4" dbtype="varchar" precision="255" phptype="string" null="false" default=""/>
<field key="district5" dbtype="varchar" precision="255" phptype="string" null="false" default=""/>
<field key="district6" dbtype="varchar" precision="255" phptype="string" null="false" default=""/>
<field key="district7" dbtype="varchar" precision="255" phptype="string" null="false" default=""/>
<field key="district8" dbtype="varchar" precision="255" phptype="string" null="false" default=""/>
<field key="district9" dbtype="varchar" precision="255" phptype="string" null="false" default=""/>
<field key="district10" dbtype="varchar" precision="255" phptype="string" null="false" default=""/>
<field key="district11" dbtype="varchar" precision="255" phptype="string" null="false" default=""/>
<field key="district12" dbtype="varchar" precision="255" phptype="string" null="false" default=""/>
<field key="district13" dbtype="varchar" precision="255" phptype="string" null="false" default=""/>
<field key="district14" dbtype="varchar" precision="255" phptype="string" null="false" default=""/>
<field key="district15" dbtype="varchar" precision="255" phptype="string" null="false" default=""/>
<field key="district16" dbtype="varchar" precision="255" phptype="string" null="false" default=""/>
<field key="district17" dbtype="varchar" precision="255" phptype="string" null="false" default=""/>
<field key="district18" dbtype="varchar" precision="255" phptype="string" null="false" default=""/>
<field key="district19" dbtype="varchar" precision="255" phptype="string" null="false" default=""/>
<field key="district20" dbtype="varchar" precision="255" phptype="string" null="false" default=""/>
<field key="district21" dbtype="varchar" precision="255" phptype="string" null="false" default=""/>
<field key="district22" dbtype="varchar" precision="255" phptype="string" null="false" default=""/>
<field key="district23" dbtype="varchar" precision="255" phptype="string" null="false" default=""/>
<field key="district24" dbtype="varchar" precision="255" phptype="string" null="false" default=""/>
<field key="district25" dbtype="varchar" precision="255" phptype="string" null="false" default=""/>
<field key="district26" dbtype="varchar" precision="255" phptype="string" null="false" default=""/>
<field key="district27" dbtype="varchar" precision="255" phptype="string" null="false" default=""/>
<field key="district28" dbtype="varchar" precision="255" phptype="string" null="false" default=""/>
<field key="district29" dbtype="varchar" precision="255" phptype="string" null="false" default=""/>
<field key="district30" dbtype="varchar" precision="255" phptype="string" null="false" default=""/>
<field key="district31" dbtype="varchar" precision="255" phptype="string" null="false" default=""/>
<field key="district32" dbtype="varchar" precision="255" phptype="string" null="false" default=""/>
<field key="district33" dbtype="varchar" precision="255" phptype="string" null="false" default=""/>
<field key="district34" dbtype="varchar" precision="255" phptype="string" null="false" default=""/>
<field key="postcode1" dbtype="decimal" precision="11.0" phptype="string" null="false" default=""/>
<field key="postcode2" dbtype="decimal" precision="11.0" phptype="string" null="false" default=""/>
<field key="postcode3" dbtype="decimal" precision="11.0" phptype="string" null="false" default=""/>
<field key="postcode4" dbtype="decimal" precision="11.0" phptype="string" null="false" default=""/>
<field key="postcode5" dbtype="decimal" precision="11.0" phptype="string" null="false" default=""/>
<field key="postcode6" dbtype="decimal" precision="11.0" phptype="string" null="false" default=""/>
<field key="postcode7" dbtype="decimal" precision="11.0" phptype="string" null="false" default=""/>
<field key="postcode8" dbtype="decimal" precision="11.0" phptype="string" null="false" default=""/>
<field key="postcode9" dbtype="decimal" precision="11.0" phptype="string" null="false" default=""/>
<field key="postcode10" dbtype="decimal" precision="11.0" phptype="string" null="false" default=""/>
<field key="postcode11" dbtype="decimal" precision="11.0" phptype="string" null="false" default=""/>
<field key="postcode12" dbtype="decimal" precision="11.0" phptype="string" null="false" default=""/>
<field key="postcode13" dbtype="decimal" precision="11.0" phptype="string" null="false" default=""/>
<field key="postcode14" dbtype="decimal" precision="11.0" phptype="string" null="false" default=""/>
<field key="postcode15" dbtype="decimal" precision="11.0" phptype="string" null="false" default=""/>
<field key="postcode16" dbtype="decimal" precision="11.0" phptype="string" null="false" default=""/>
<field key="postcode17" dbtype="decimal" precision="11.0" phptype="string" null="false" default=""/>
<field key="postcode18" dbtype="decimal" precision="11.0" phptype="string" null="false" default=""/>
<field key="postcode19" dbtype="decimal" precision="11.0" phptype="string" null="false" default=""/>
<field key="postcode20" dbtype="decimal" precision="11.0" phptype="string" null="false" default=""/>
<field key="postcode21" dbtype="decimal" precision="11.0" phptype="string" null="false" default=""/>
<field key="postcode22" dbtype="decimal" precision="11.0" phptype="string" null="false" default=""/>
<field key="postcode23" dbtype="decimal" precision="11.0" phptype="string" null="false" default=""/>
<field key="postcode24" dbtype="decimal" precision="11.0" phptype="string" null="false" default=""/>
<field key="postcode25" dbtype="decimal" precision="11.0" phptype="string" null="false" default=""/>
<field key="postcode26" dbtype="decimal" precision="11.0" phptype="string" null="false" default=""/>
<field key="postcode27" dbtype="decimal" precision="11.0" phptype="string" null="false" default=""/>
<field key="postcode28" dbtype="decimal" precision="11.0" phptype="string" null="false" default=""/>
<field key="postcode29" dbtype="decimal" precision="11.0" phptype="string" null="false" default=""/>
<field key="postcode30" dbtype="decimal" precision="11.0" phptype="string" null="false" default=""/>
<field key="postcode31" dbtype="decimal" precision="11.0" phptype="string" null="false" default=""/>
<field key="postcode32" dbtype="decimal" precision="11.0" phptype="string" null="false" default=""/>
<field key="postcode33" dbtype="decimal" precision="11.0" phptype="string" null="false" default=""/>
<field key="postcode34" dbtype="decimal" precision="11.0" phptype="string" null="false" default=""/>
<field key="date132" dbtype="date" phptype="date" null="true" default="0000-00-00"/>
<field key="country" dbtype="varchar" precision="255" phptype="string" null="false" default=""/>
<field key="phonenumber" dbtype="varchar" precision="255" phptype="string" null="false" default=""/>
<field key="email128" dbtype="varchar" precision="255" phptype="string" null="false" default=""/>
<field key="companyname" dbtype="varchar" precision="255" phptype="string" null="false" default=""/>
<field key="packagetype" dbtype="varchar" precision="255" phptype="string" null="false" default=""/>
<field key="weightkgs" dbtype="decimal" precision="11.0" phptype="string" null="false" default=""/>
<field key="width" dbtype="decimal" precision="11.0" phptype="string" null="false" default=""/>
<field key="length" dbtype="decimal" precision="11.0" phptype="string" null="false" default=""/>
<field key="height" dbtype="decimal" precision="11.0" phptype="string" null="false" default=""/>
<field key="details" dbtype="text" phptype="string" null="false" default=""/>
<index alias="PRIMARY" name="PRIMARY" primary="true" unique="true">
    <column key="id" collation="A" null="false" />
</index>
    <aggregate alias="Resource" class="modResource" local="resource_id" foreign="id" cardinality="one" owner="foreign" />
    <aggregate alias="Creator" class="modUser" local="createdby" foreign="id" cardinality="one" owner="foreign" />
</object>
</model>
```

There is a form on the front end that users fill in [link to form](http://bit.ly/1BYOLyn) . This is automatically recorded in the database. 
The info in the database is displayed automatically in a table on this page [link to table](http://bit.ly/1LOsSl5) 
The users also select 1 district and 1 postcode,  but, in the database every district & postcode is there. 
I want to display in the table only the chosen district & postcode. 
All the other districts and postcodes are also in their own columns but I want the code to ignore the empty fields that were not chosen.
One user could choose district4 & postcode15, the next user could choose district28 & postcode14. 
On the front end table I want to display in a child row the actual chosen district & postcode.

Comment: It really isn't clear what is being asked... how is the table being populated? Is all of that information already in the table or is it loaded via php or ajax? How does the user select the district & postcode? I demo on jsFiddle would be very helpful.

Comment: Hi Mottie I have added the extra info into the question with links to the demo pages. I will delete the links later because this site is not launched yet.

Comment: If you fill the form in the data will automatically display in the table (the box for district & postcode do not display until on the form until a province has been selected).

Comment: For example; this field key displays name [[+yourname]] this displays the phone number [[+phonenumber]] it is using the MODX CMS with the following extensions: 
MIGX integrated to record the data and bloX to display (call) it into the child rows.
I have 34 districts & 34 postcodes each with their own individual field key in the XML.

Comment: I think what you are asking is actually related to the CMS. I'm not familiar with MODX and MIGX; I think it might be appropriate to add those labels to this question.

Comment: I added MODX, it didn't recognise MIGX.....Maybe I will post the question onto the modx forum.

Comment: maybe better to ask at MODX - Forums, and if it is MIGX - specific here: http://forums.modx.com/board?board=271

Comment: @Bruno17 , the question has now been asked at the MIGX forum on MODX http://bit.ly/1FJ0NGP